# How to apply a non uniform stretch to an image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry, linear-algebra

Currently I am using the code below to take an image where each column of pixels represent a different width (mm) in the real world. Imagine a label wrapped around a bottle. My input image is what you see when you look directly at the bottle (less perspective). I am trying to unwrap that label so the flattened result has an exact 1pixel:1mm ratio. Also the bottle is not circular but I have an equation to represent it's curvature. **Is there a better way to do this where the result is always the same and the de-streched image is more uniform?**

See below where the top image is the original image and the bottom is what I hope to achieve.
[image]

The equation and curve below gives me a compression factor for every column of pixels where the pixels at column 1741 represent 0.773802mm
[image]

Currently I am using the probabilistic code below to replicate/remove columns of pixels based on the compression factor. Due to the probabilistic nature, given the same input each output is different and stretch correction is not as uniform as I would like. **NOTE: the striped images above were not generated with this code**

```
import random
import cv2
import numpy as np


def regularise_image_stretch(img: cv2.Mat, compensations: np.ndarray) -> cv2.Mat:
    '''apply a non uniform stretch to an image based on an equation that maps column idx
    to compression/stretch needed to make the pixel:mm ratio uniform across all cols

    Args:
        img (cv2.Mat): non uniform image
        compensations (np.ndarray): array of compensations per column idx generated from an equation

    Returns:
        cv2.Mat: an image where every pixel represents 1mm
    '''
    def decision(val: float) -> tuple[str, bool, float]:
        '''Based on the compression factor use a probabistic approach to decide 
        whether to insert a copy of the previous column or to delete a column. 

        Args:
            val (float): compression value

        Returns:
            tuple[str, bool, float]: ("add" || "remove", should be applied, probability)
        '''
        addrem = "rem"
        probability = 1 - val
        if probability > 0:
            addrem = "add"

        probability = abs(probability)

        return (addrem, random.random() < probability, probability)

    modimg = img.copy()

    res = list(map(decision, compensations))
    new_img = []
    previous_col = modimg[:, 0, :]

    # add/replicate columns based on compression factor
    for i, col in enumerate(modimg.transpose(1,0,2)):
        addrem, shouldapply, _ = res[i]
        new_img.append(col)

        if shouldapply:
            if addrem == "add":
                new_img.append(previous_col)
            else:
                new_img.pop(-1)

        previous_col = col

    # as a list is being used above fix image orientation
    new_img = cv2.rotate(np.array(new_img), cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
    new_img = cv2.flip(np.array(new_img), 0)
    new_img = cv2.resize(new_img, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
    return new_img


img = cv2.imread("./stripes.jpg")

new_img = regularise_image_stretch(img, compensations)
cv2.imwrite("./modifiend2.png", np.vstack([new_img, img]))
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this :)

Comment: ditch "probabilistic" interpretations. I don't see any benefit to that here. -- ditch that equation. it's just a quadratic, which is insufficient to model the "surface texture" of a cylinder. -- use `cv::remap()`, build the lookup table from (projected) polar coordinates. sounds more complicated than it is. if you want to, I can demonstrate. -- please provide a representative picture of a label on a bottle/cylinder, or explain how the synthetic warped image was generated. -- did you take the [tour] yet? I don't see that you have the badge that comes with it.

Comment: example of the texture produced by unrolling the cylinder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQAld.png this assumes that the cylinder uses the full image width. if it does not, distortion.

Comment: and here's how a cylinder _should_ look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB8fe.png

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Had a look at the tour there, I joined 8yrs ago and don't remember seeing it. As for remap, having a look now. I'll let you know how I go.

Answer (score 1):

@Christoph Rackwitz you legend. Thanks for the tip. The code below is working perfectly :). The images below are rollers from a production line. Each of these rollers are the same width. Using this I was able to generate pol1d to determine the correct mapping so that all rollers now appear to be the same width using cv.map.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def update_map(map_x, map_y, poly_vals):
    for i in range(map_x.shape[0]):
        map_x[i,:] = [poly_vals[x] for x in range(map_x.shape[1])]
    for j in range(map_y.shape[1]):
        map_y[:,j] = [y for y in range(map_y.shape[0])]

            
src = cv2.imread('./dec1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    
map_x = np.zeros((src.shape[0], src.shape[1]), dtype=np.float32)
map_y = np.zeros((src.shape[0], src.shape[1]), dtype=np.float32)


""" poly = poly1d([-1.88998073e-30,  4.54152495e-26, -4.63866537e-22,  2.57875197e-18,
       -7.81961948e-15,  8.97968101e-12, -4.74328547e-09,  1.00701327e-04,
        7.72461327e-01, -2.75718623e-01])"""
poly_vals = np.poly1d(mypoly)(range(src.shape[1]))
                           

update_map(map_x, map_y, poly_vals)
dst = cv2.remap(src, map_x, map_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.imwrite("destretched.png", np.vstack([dst, src]))
plt.imshow(dst)
```